# Cheking if variable is undefined

Tags: node.js, undefined, undefined-behavior

So I want to check if a variable is undefined in node.js. So far I work like this:

```
if(typeof object.data.items[1] === 'undefined')
{
    break;  
}
else
{
    console.log("Defined");         
}
```

But it gives me this error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined".

Any ideas on how to bypass this error while still checking if it's undefined?

Comment: Try to check first if  typeof object === 'undefined'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check both object and object.data is defined first.

```
if(object && object.data && typeof object.data.items[1] === 'undefined')
{
    break;  
}
else
{
    console.log("Defined");         
}
```

or

```
if(!object || !object.data || typeof object.data.items[1] === 'undefined')
    {
        break;  
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Defined");         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `object` variable is undefined too. Try the following code:

```
if(
    typeof object === 'undefined' ||
    typeof object.data === 'undefined' ||
    typeof object.data.items[1] === 'undefined')
{
    break;  
}
else
{
    console.log("Defined");         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!_.get(object,['data','items',1]))
{
    break;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access a property of JSON object you have to ensure that left side of your dot operator must have some value but not undefined or null. i.e.
If you want to access `a.b.c.d` then you have to make sure that each left side property has some value. You can use @rijin's answer.